# How to read request attribute in a JSP after a POST request from the same JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I'm working on a webapp with JAVA servlet backend and JSP frontend. This is my problem:
in jsp page i have three select form, the options of this form are taken from the DB, so when i load the page the servlet take the info from DB and set attribute in the request and i fill the options of the form. What i would to do is, when i select an item in the first form, the option in the other two form change depending on the selected value. To do this my idea was to take the value of the first form make a POST request with javascript to the servlet, elaborate data, set the request attributes inside the servlet and forwarding to the same jsp. At this point i don't understand how to retrive the attributes i set, cause i don't really understand if the servlet is reloaded or not. I tried using javascritp with no result, i don't think this is strange case but i don't find an answer.

When the first select change this code is triggered:

```js
 function postJSON(data){
        try {
            const response = fetch("<%=contextPath%>/Dispatcher?controllerAction=RegistrationManagement.matchComuni",{
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
        }).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.status);
        });
        
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error: ", error);
        }
    }
```

This is part of method that elaborate data:

```java
public static void matchComuni(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        DAOFactory daoFactory= null;
        Logger logger = LogService.getApplicationLogger();
        List<Regione> regioni = new ArrayList<Regione>(); 
        List<Citta> listaCitta = new ArrayList<Citta>();
        List<Provincia> province = new ArrayList<Provincia>();
        String selectedRegioneJSON;
        String regioniJSON;
        String listaCittaJSON;
        String provinceJSON;
        try {
            daoFactory=DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(Configuration.DAO_IMPL, null);
            daoFactory.beginTransaction();
            
            RegioneDAO regioneDAO = daoFactory.getRegioneDAO();
            regioni = regioneDAO.findRegioni();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            regioniJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(regioni);
            selectedRegioneJSON = request.getParameter("selectedRegione");
            Regione selctedRegione = mapper.readValue(selectedRegioneJSON, Regione.class);
            CittaDAO cittaDAO = daoFactory.getCittaDAO();
            listaCitta = cittaDAO.findCittaByRegione(selctedRegione.getIdRegione());
            listaCittaJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(listaCitta);
            ProvinciaDAO provinciaDAO = daoFactory.getProvinciaDAO();
            province = provinciaDAO.findProvinceByRegione(selctedRegione);
            provinceJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(province);

 
            request.setAttribute("regioniJSON", regioniJSON);
            request.setAttribute("listaCittaJSON", listaCittaJSON);
            request.setAttribute("provinceJSON", provinceJSON);
            request.setAttribute("viewUrl", "/registration/registration");
```

at this point in the servlet i received the correct data and all the elaboration are fine so the data are send to the jsp with request.setAttribute(), but i don't find how to read the new data. I don't understand if at this point the jsp is completely reloaded or partial reloaded or the same as before the POST request.

I tried to read the new data in javascript with:
`let var = '<%(String)request.getAttribute(provinceJSON)%>';` but return null

```js
let urlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let paramJSON = urlParam.get("provinceJSON");
```

return null

```js
let urlParam = new URLSearchParams(response.url);
let paramJSON = urlParam.get("provinceJSON");
```

return null

As i said before i don't think this is a strange scenario, but i don't find a solution, i hope in yours help.

P.S. I'm sorry for my bad english it isn't my first language.

Comment: It is a strange scenarion, why don't you think so, the `UrlSearchParam` is JS object, and it's not available in JSP. JSP is a serverside object, and it'is not available in the browser. Mistreating both makes things harder to understand and of course it never works. Also why you serialize data objects to JSON? If you never use that objects on the client? In JSP you can write any string either JSON string or HTML string or XML string, doesn't matter, but the client is responsible to read a data prerendered on the server. The JSP is using tags, scriptlets, or EL expressions to retrieve the data.

Comment: @RomanC thank you for the answer, so i use jsp because i'm forced to do it. Obviusly i use the objects serialized in different ways in client side, although the jsp is a server side object as you said it can be used to interact with client side using html and javascript and so i do. Using a jsp with support of JS is there a method to retrieve data from server after the jsp is rendered by the server?

Comment: In the typical MVC application the data is retrieved by the controller, then it's stored in the model object. The model object is pushed to the view, so it's able to access the data. The view can access the model. Nothing more, nor any JS is used to retrieve the data when html is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider returning a JSON response from the servlet instead, which can be parsed after fetching. The jackson-dataformat-xml Maven dependency can be used to convert a Java object to JSON.

In the servlet:

```java
var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // from Jackson
response.setContentType("application/json");
var writer = response.getWriter();
var result = Map.of(
    "regioni", regioni
    // and anything else to send back
);
writer.print(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result));
writer.flush();
```

On the frontend:

```js
fetch('/Dispatcher?controllerAction=RegistrationManagement.matchComuni', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // access the values, e.g. data.regioni
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in my case this resolve in a error, cause i use a dispatcher for redirecting to the correct servlet and when the servlet has terminated his job gives control back to the dispatcher that forward to the jsp, so if i flush writer when the control return back to dispatcher it can't execute forward method.

Comment: @Annibale You need to handle different types of requests differently with conditional logic. For AJAX, they should directly write the output. Other requests that should return HTML should be forwarded. This is the standard method for handling it.

Comment: Hi, i followed your advice and it worked! Now the dispatcher doesn't interfere when there is an AJAX request and with your code i can handle the data as i need. Thank you so much!